# by what to replace TSysCharSet that is deprecated under nextgen?

Tags: delphi

This is the declaration of TSysCharSet under delphi Berlin

```
TSysCharSet = set of Char deprecated; // Holds Char values in the ordinal range of 0..255 only.
```

it is now deprecated, but by what to replace it ? i just need to gave to my function some set of char like [' ', #9, #13, #10]

Comment: I'm not seeing any replacement, according to the docs. The docs basically say that if you want to use it to unicode characters, then sorry. Strangely, it doesn't even mention that it's deprecated. http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/System.SysUtils.TSysCharSet

Comment: Sets aren't suitable because of the implementation limitations. Find a way that doesn't involve sets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you need is to carry around a group of (unicode) characters then you don't need TSysCharSet.  Just use a dynamic array of char:

```
var
   MyCharArray : TArray<char>;

begin
   MyCharArray := [' ',#9,#13,#10]; 
end;
```

[TSysCharSet](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/System.SysUtils.TSysCharSet) was primarily used in the [CharInSet](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/System.SysUtils.CharInSet) routine; In the docs they refer to [TCharHelper](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/System.Character.TCharHelper) as a replacement for CharInSet since a TSysCharSet cannot contain unicode characters.

```
uses System.Character;

var
   WhiteSpace : TSysCharSet;
   ac : ansichar;

   c : char;

begin
   // replace this....
   ac := #9;
   WhiteSpace := [' ',#9,#13,#10];

   if CharInSet(ac, WhiteSpace) then
      begin
      end;  

   // ...with this:

   c := #9;
   if c.IsWhiteSpace then
      begin
      end
end
```

Comment: Results will differ though because IsWhitespace will catch more characters.